# Combine columns ignoring nan

Tags: python, pandas, string-concatenation

I want to create a concatenated column, separated by commas, in the most efficient and generalisable way:

```
df fruit colour
0   apple green
1   NaN   orange 
2   NaN   NaN

listy= ["fruit", "colour"]
df[listy].apply(lambda x:",".join(x.dropna()),axis=1))
Type error: sequence item 3: expected str instance, float found
```

Excepted Output

```
0 apple, green
1 Orange 
2 NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some numeric values, convert them to `string`s:

```
listy= ["fruit", "colour"]
out=df[listy].apply(lambda x:", ".join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1).replace('', np.nan)

print (out)
0    apple, green
1          orange
2             NaN
dtype: object
```

Or:

```
listy= ["fruit", "colour"]
out = df[listy].stack().astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join).reindex(df.index)
print (out)
0    apple, green
1          orange
2             NaN
dtype: object
```

If need find numeric values at least in one column try convert to numeric and filter them:

```
listy= ["fruit", "colour"]
print(df.loc[df[listy].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notna().any(axis=1), listy])
```

Comment: Stole your replace to handle all NaN rows ;)

Comment: @Learningisamess - yop, I see.

Comment: @jezrael, is there any way to find the problematic rows, for future reference?

Comment: @jezrael, when I apply the ```.stack() ``` solution to a df with many rows and more columns I'm not getting the right answer for some reason? The lambda function works but too inefficient

Comment: @asd - DataFrame has default index values? If use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` still same problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html

```py
df[listy].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().str.join(', '),axis=1).replace('', np.nan)
```

Without the replace:

```py
def column_join_transform(s:pd.Series)->str|float:
    s = s.dropna()
    if s.empty:
        return np.nan
    return s.str.join(', ')
df[listy].apply( column_join_transform, axis=1)
```

Second edit, faster way of doing it by applying a function on the underlying numpy array:

```py
def np_column_join_transform(row):
    join = ', '.join([x for x in row if x == x])
    if not join:
        return np.nan
    return join

df.apply( np_column_join_transform, axis=1, raw=True)
```

Benchmarked on my machine to be 20x faster on a dataframe of shape (1000, 3)

Comment: Why is my code wrong?

Comment: You need to cast your values to `str` before calling join, like `",".join(map(str, x.dropna()))`

Comment: Is there a more efficient way - without lambda?

Comment: The lambda is not inefficient in terms of computation performance. Let me update my answer to bypass the replace (which should only be a minor optimization).

Comment: Check my update for a new answer.

Comment: New update with a sped up method.

Answer (score 0):

Other but very similar method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "fruit": ["apple", np.nan, np.nan],
    "colour": ["green", "orange", np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.assign(comb = df['fruit'].astype(str) + df['colour'].astype(str))
df['comb'] = df.comb.str.replace('nan','')

print(df)

fruit  colour        comb
0  apple   green  applegreen
1    NaN  orange      orange
2    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the error using a check within the `apply`, for instance with the walrus operator and a ternary:

```
df[listy].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(X) if len(X:=x.dropna()) else float('nan'), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    apple, green
1          orange
2             NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way - without lambda?

Comment: @asd you can use a named function, but a lambda is not particularly inefficient. This approach should however be more efficient than chaining a `replace`